# What is wrong with this regular expression, trying to match pattern name1.name2?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match a pattern, `"john.doe"`, with this regular expression:

```
 ^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]))/?$
```

I can't get it to match.

Comment: did you miss out a `+` at the end of the second name?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov is correct, http://regexr.com?30q26. Dmitri, you should post that as an answer and win yourself some reputation.

Comment: And you shouldn't allow the "." in first [] because it'll dismiss the "." between the words.

Comment: @tpaksu Actually it works if added a `+` sign at the second group. See the tests here: http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E((%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_%5C.-%5D%2B)%5C.(%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_%5C.-%5D)%2B)%2F%3F%24&input=john.doe%0Afirst.second%0Aand.this.works%0Aand.this.also.works

Answer (score 1):

Regex is just oversized

```
list($name1, $name2) = explode('.', $name, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `/^([\w\-]+)\.([\w\-]+)$/` should work for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @M42. Modified the regexp to include `-`

Answer (score -1):

Like Dmitri Chubarov said (credits to him),  you only have to add a `+` sign at the second group:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+))/?$
```

```
^((([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))/?$
```

This will work with:

```
jhon.doe
this.also.work
this.will.also.work
```

But not with:

```
x..
..x
..
...
....
.....
```

http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E(((%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_-%5D%2B%5C.)*%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_-%5D%2B)%5C.((%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_-%5D%2B%5C.)*%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_-%5D%2B))%2F%3F%24&input=john.doe%0Afirst.second%0Aand.this.works%0Aand.this.also.works%0Ax.x%0Ax..%0A..x%0A..%0A...%0A....%0A.....

Comment: This matches `x..`, `..x` and even `...` too.

Comment: Why to downvote if the initial pattern is including the dots and the OP have not complained about it?

Comment: I have changed the regex to not match the sequences prointed by @KingCrunch.